# Python - TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python

I wrote a code that strips two values from a set of 50 items from a website and stored them into a list. However, when I check to see how many values there are via `len()` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

response = links

def get_links(response):
    list_links = []
    for i in range(len(response)):
        url = response[i].select('a')[0]['href']
        date = datetime.strptime(response[i].select('span.field-content')[1].text, '%A, %B %d, %Y')
        list_links.append((url, date))

get_links(response)

page = get_links(response)

assert len(page) == 50
```

any ideas?

Comment: You are passing links to response. So, Where is 'links' variable defined in your code?

Comment: Your `get_links()` function doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: I can't upvote yet, but I eventually will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_links` function does not return anything add a return statement to it + iterating through the list is more optimal

here is an improved version of your code with the return statement

```
def get_links(response):
    list_links = []
    for link in response:
        url = link.select('a')[0]['href']
        date = datetime.strptime(link.select('span.field-content')[1].text, '%A, %B %d, %Y')
        list_links.append((url, date))
    return list_links
```